# Trouble understanding how to index array items

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is an example from the [Ruby documentation for the Array class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#label-Accessing+Elements)

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr[2, 3]
 => [3, 4, 5] 
arr[1, 2]
 => [2, 3]
```

Umm, what? Help, anyone? Why this discrepancy between the [2,3] and [1,2] behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the bold line taken from the documentation of [**`Accessing Elements`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#label-Accessing+Elements):

> Elements in an array can be retrieved using the #[] method. It can take a single integer argument (a numeric index), ***a pair of arguments (start and length)*** or a range.

When you are using **a pair of arguments (start and length)**,it will return a **subarray starting at the start index and continuing for length elements.**

In the line `arr[1, 2]` - 1 is a starting index and 2 is the length. Means you are telling starting from index `1` of the `arr`,you want to fetch 2 elements.

In the line `arr[2, 3]` - 2 is a starting index and 3 is the length. Means you are telling starting from index `2` of the `arr`,you want to fetch 3 elements.

Read [**`Array#[]`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) also.

Answer (score 1):

There is no discrepancy here (Ruby array index starts with zero)

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
      (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  #=> their index/positions       

arr[2,3] #=> arr[start,length]- start at 2nd index; it has value 3 and get 3 elements [3,4,5]
arr[1,2] #=> arr[start,length]- start at 1st index; it has value 2 and get 2 elements [2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to see if you are using an array of letters.

```
>> arr = %w[a b c d e f g]
=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
>> arr[2, 3]
=> ["c", "d", "e"]
>> arr[1, 2]
=> ["b", "c"]
```

The two prior descriptions apply here, but you have less of a chance for not translating what you are asking for and what you are getting.

Index of an array starts at 0, so when asking for the 3 elements starting from index 2, you are getting c, d and e.

When you are asking for 2 elements starting from index 1, you get b and c.